# Android: How to stop soft keyboard from displaying the split action bar above it when it's in view?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

My app uses a split action bar interface, so my menu action items are in a bar at the bottom of the screen. Whenever the soft keyboard pops up, the bottom action bar moves up too and hovers above the keyboard. How do I stop the bottom bar from moving, and just let the keyboard cover it up when it's open? If it matters, I am using actionbarsherlock.

Comment: insert this code into your oncreate method  "getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);"

Answer (score 5):

Solved this by adding 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to each actiivty declaration in the manifest.

Comment: Do you even know how many solutions there are out there to this that don't work. Awesome.